# Generate Eclipse PDT from C#

Tags: c#, eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-pdt

I have library written in C# with the standard C# documentation on my methods, as in the example below, and Visual Studio automatically does autocompletion and pops up the various argument descriptions.  I use SandCastle helper to generate "compiled html" documentation pages.

My users seem be half Windows and half Linux developers, with the latter mostly using Eclipse.  Can anyone suggest a simple cross-platform option that would still work for Visual Studio and for generating manual pages, but also give me Eclipse autocompletion and hover-over popups (e.g. auto-generate the needed PDT files)?  If this involves modifying my C# documentation to use something more like Javadoc, I could do that.  Ideally, of course, I prefer not to create a code branch or duplicate my documentation...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Puts the current group into DHT mode, but without specifying a target size and without setting aside extra members. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ReplicationFactor">Requested data replication factor</param>
    /// <param name="ExpectedGroupSize">Your estimate of the typical size of this group (N); a multiple of the replication factor</param>
    /// <param name="MinimumGroupSize">The smallest group size at which the DHT will accept DHTPut/DHTGet commands</param>
    /// <remarks>If the replication factor is too small, you run the risk that our random hashing scheme could leave some affinity
    /// group with too few, or too many members.  </remarks>
    public void DHTEnable(int ReplicationFactor, int ExpectedGroupSize, int MinimumGroupSize)
    {
        DHTEnable(ReplicationFactor, ExpectedGroupSize, MinimumGroupSize, int.MaxValue);
    }
```

Comment: So am I somehow doing things totally bass-ackwards?  Is there a big crowd using libraries coded originally in .NET on Linux via Mono?  How do you folks deal with editing / autocompletion?  Do you just use visual studio in such situations?

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like this was the wrong forum for me to pose my question in, plus I probably had the file-type extension wrong (PDT seems to be specific to PHP files; I'm focused on use of Eclipse in languages that can talk to C# libraries).  Anyhow, I'll post to the Eclipse developers forum; probably a better match to the question...